# What does this iptable rule mean?

Tags: linux, iptables

What does this `iptables` rule mean?

```
iptables -t raw -I OUTPUT -j CT -p udp -m udp --dport 69 --helper tftp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule seems to be part of a lager set of rules.

- `-t raw -I OUPUT`: insert this rule into the beginning of the OUTPUT chain of the table `raw`
- `-j CT`: if the conditions are met jump to target `CT`

#### now the conditions

- `-p udp`: protocol must be udp
- `-m udp`: use the extension `udp` - needed to be able to filter on udp-ports
- `--dport  69`: apply to  udp datagrams with destination port 69
- `--helper tftp`: for tracking of related datagrams use the expectations for `tftp`

reference: ["helpers" on regit.org](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/secure-use-of-helpers/)

Answer (score 2):

In a less technical explanation:

- `-t raw -I OUTPUT`: insert this rule inside `OUTPUT` chain of `raw` table. This special table is used only for configuring packets so that they are exempt from connection tracking. It may look obvious but this table only has the `PREROUTING` and `OUTPUT` chains, since `FORWARD` requires some connection tracking.
- `-j CT`: Jump to target named `CT`. This is a custom target, and the sky is the limmit since you can combine `ACCEPT` and `LOG` as a simple example on one target. You will need the rest of the rules to get the real meaning of `CT` target here.
- `-p udp`: Protocol to match the rule is udp. As per manpages, the specified protocol can be one of tcp, `udp`, `udplite`, `icmp`, `esp`, `ah`, `sctp` or the special keyword `all`, or it can be a numeric value, representing one of these protocols or a different one. You can get the list of [protocol numbers here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml).
- `-m udp`: Match `udp` extension options. This is somehow an overkill since the options inside udp match are `--sport` and `--dport` and can be omited as [`iptables-extensions`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) manpage states: *If the -p or --protocol was specified and if and only if an unknown option is encountered, iptables will try load a match module of the same name as the protocol, to try making the option available.*
- `--dport 69`: Destinaton port = 69, and `--dport` match option from udp
- `--helper tftp`: Some protocols behave in a "weird" way and helpers need to be used to manage that behavior. ftp is one example where one port is used for command/signaling and other for data transfer. More on [helpers here](http://home.regit.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/secure-conntrack-helpers.html).

Comment: CT is not a custom target

Comment: Is not at the default iptables targets so, yeah, is a custom one. Maybe a software you are using or the distribution you are currently using has it, but is not part of the default set of targets: http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-targets-and-jumps.html

Comment: CT target is used by helpers to specify parameters used during conntrack creation, this target (Conntrack Target) is created by the [xt_CT Kernel module](https://lwn.net/Articles/371025/)